# Powershell - Get Logged in User on Remote Host and Store Username as Variable

Tags: powershell, wmi, wmi-query, wmic

Trying to use a Get-WmiObject to get the currently or last logged in username on a remote pc, then store that value to a variable so I can later use it as part of a path.

I try this, but my variable just comes up blank.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

```
$gottenUserName = (Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $thaTargetHost -Namespace root\cimv2 -Class Win32_ComputerSystem)[0].UserName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take out the index piece ([0]) at the end as it is not needed when using this class. You will only get back a single value from Win32_ComputerSystem

```
$gottenUserName = (Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $thaTargetHost -Namespace root\cimv2 -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).UserName
```

Comment: I'm still not getting any value

Comment: When you just query Win32_ComputerSystem, is there anything showing up in the Username property? `Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $thaTargetHost -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select Username`

Comment: Win32_ComputerSystem does not have UserName property

Comment: Yes it does. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102(v=vs.85).aspx). The property description is near the bottom of the page.

Comment: Ah, it is not one of the properties that gets displayed but sure it is there. Thanks @boeprox

Comment: If I run it like that I just get

Username
--------

Comment: if I run it as `$gottenUsername = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $thaTargetHost -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select Username`

It stores the value as _@{Username=}_

Comment: It appears that the property simply does not have a value in it at the time you ran the command. You should find a system that you know has someone logged in (like your own computer) and run my command again to see what happens.

Comment: ok it works that time, but the string stored in the variable is `@{Username=DOMAIN\username`  (domain and username are shown correctly I edited them for privacy reasons).  Is there a way I can just get the _username_ to store in the variable?  Also, is there a way to get the last logged in user so it works even if the user is offline?  Thanks again.

Comment: Try this: `$gottenUserName = ((Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $thaTargetHost -Namespace root\cimv2 -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).UserName -split '\\')[1]`